# Microsoft Security Essentials expired

Tags: windows-7, ms-security-essentials

I use MS Security Essentials on my Windows 7 x64. I've been using it for years and since a few days now it does not update the definition files.

I tried to do it manually, and I get the following error (translated):

```
Error code: 0x80070070
Error description: The license for application usage has expired.
The computer is exposed to malware infections.
```

As much as I know, SE is free to use on an activated Windows and does not expire.

What happened?

Comment: Have you kept Security Essentials up to date?

Comment: Yes. Its last update is of 17th of November.

Comment: What version do you have installed.  I would uninstall it, and install the current version, because MSE at one time was paid and I suspect you have that version installed.

Comment: Client program: 4.6.305.0
Engine: 1.1.11104.0
Virus definition: 1.187.2382.0
Malware definition: 1.187.2382.0
Network monitor engine: 2.1.11005.0
Network monitor definition: 113.26.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the new definition files take up to 107 MB in file size. I simply has 70 MB of free space on my C drive and it is not enough...

After freeing up some space, SE could update itself. Great...

Comment: Do you really mean 70 MB and not 70 GB? A system with that little free disk space is not going to work very well. I suggest that you run disk cleanup and tick only "Temporary Internet Files", "Temporary Files" and "Thumbnails" for a start, then when that's done see how much free disk space you have.

Comment: Believe me, I tried a lots of things :) My C partition is only 100 GB and it has been taken up a few installed program. I guess, C partition requires a whole disk...a few years ago 20 GB was sufficient. Nowadays TBs are needed to have a proper system.

Comment: There could be available space which needs to be reclaimed by running `chkdsk c: /f` from a command prompt run with Administrator privileges, but with so little free disk space I suspect that could be **dangerous**. You know the only real solution is to get a larger disk drive, don't you? ;)

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall MSE and reinstall Make sure you have correct year, date and time, could be SSL issue.